# spaces/nulls inserted into redirected output of the cmd command

Tags: batch-file, null, output, spaces

When I run the command

```
wmic memorychip get capacity
```

from the command line in the cmd window, the output on the screen looks like:

```
Capacity    
2147483648
```

However, if I add this command to a batch file and try to redirect the output to a file, like:

```
wmic memorychip get capacity >> %LOG%
```

(where %LOG% is just my log file where I want to append the data), it gets saved in the log file as:

```
C a p a c i t y         

 2 1 4 7 4 8 3 6 4 8
```

Here spaces got inserted before each character. In the Notepad++ it shows NULs inserted, for some reason I am not able to paste it here :(

Does anybody know why the output is changed such a way and how to avoid this transformation?

Answer (score 3):

Unicode for sure.

Try

```
wmic memorychip get capacity |more>> %LOG%
```

Comment: it may look nicer in your logfile, if you use `wmic memorychip get capacity /value` which gives you `Capacity=2147483648`

Comment: Disagree, the `/value` did not work for the command I was using but using `|more` worked great.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the output file but cannot run the original command again, `cat original.txt | tr -d "\00" > cleaned.txt` will produce a new file with null characters removed. This command assumes common Unix shell tools are available, such as those provided by [BusyBox](https://frippery.org/busybox/) .

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that wmic works in unicode but the cmd in ascii.Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('wmic memorychip get capacity') do @for /f "delims=" %b in ("%a") do echo %b > log
```